# Why does a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ have to be linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know by definition a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ needs to be linearly Independent. However, is there a reason for why it has to be?

Comment: It's part of the definition. Generating + L.I. If it's not linearly independent but still generates, it's just called a generating set.

Comment: Otherwise you won't get coordinates with respect to this "basis". If the set does not span all of $\Bbb{R}^n$, then some points won't get coordinates at all. If the set is not linearly independent, then several combinations of coordinates give the same point. If the coordinate triples $(3,2,1)$ and $(4,3,0)$ could refer to the same point (of $\Bbb{R}^2$), then it will be difficult to discuss the points without creating some confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We *choose* definitions but there are reasons why it is a useful choice.

When a set of vectors does not span $\mathbb{R^n}$ (or a certain subspace), you can **add** a vector to this set that isn't in the span to enlarge the spanned space. You can continue this proces until the desired space is *spanned* by this set of vectors.

In a set of vectors which is *linearly dependent*, you can always **omit** a vector without changing the subspace spanned by those vectors. You can continue discarding these obsolete vectors until the set becomes *linearly independent*.

You could look at a **basis** as a set of vectors where two interesting properties come together:

- you have enough vectors to span the entire space;
- there are no (unnecessary) vectors 'in excess'.

In summary, a basis is thus a *minimal, spanning set*.

This definition of a basis guarantees that every vector of the space $\mathbb{R^n}$ can be written as a **unique linear combination** of the vectors of the basis. This leads to the meaningful introduction of coordinates (with respect to this basis), precisely the (ordered) coefficients of this unique linear combination.